# how to specify javax.persistence.Index jpa 2 with inheritance

Tags: hibernate, jpa-2.1

How do you specify an @javax.persistence.Index for a subclass?

When you specify the annotation in the superclass, Hibernate indicates that the column isn't found. But since the @Table annotation is specific to the superclass in a single table scenario, how to deal w this?

The original hibernate specific annotation referenced the table instead of *being* the @Table notation.